# Getting errors when compiling game with GCC. (error: changes meaning of ”Screen” from ”class Screen” [-fpermissive])

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt, sfml

Screen.h

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Screen
{
public:
    virtual void handleInput(sf::RenderWindow& window) = 0;
    virtual void update(sf::Time delta) = 0;
    virtual void render(sf::RenderWindow& window) = 0;

};

#endif
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include "Screen.h"

namespace sfSnake
{
class Game
{
public:
    Game();

    void run();

    void handleInput();
    void update(sf::Time delta);
    void render();

    static const int Width = 640;
    static const int Height = 480;

    static std::shared_ptr<Screen> Screen;
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window_;
    sf::Music bgMusic_;

    static const sf::Time TimePerFrame;
};
}


#endif
```

I have problems with these two headers. The code compiles fine with visual studio but won't with GCC.

I get the errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: changes meaning of ”Screen” from ”class Screen” [-fpermissive]   Screen.h    /Snake  line 6  C/C++ Problem

error: declaration of ”std::shared_ptr<Screen> sfSnake::Game::Screen” [-fpermissive]    Game.h  /Snake  line 28 C/C++ Problem
```

I have looked around for a while now and haven't found a solution. I really feel lost...
Also this is not my code it was written by the user 'jh1997sa' on reddit. [The source on github.](https://github.com/jhpy1024/sfSnake) [His thread on reddit.](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1rd9ew/c_and_sfml_heres_the_source_code_for_pong_and/)

Comment: `Screen` is both the name of a class and the name of a `shared_ptr` to a `Screen`. Have you tried what happens if you rename that one?

Comment: Well, `static shared_ptr<Screen> Screen` is just bad design, you should never have the chance of name conflicts in well designed software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't named your platform, but I presume it's some flavor of Linux running X11.  If so, this is most likely a name conflict with the Screen struct defined in X11/Xlib.h.  SFML is almost certainly using Xlib behind the scenes to interact with the windowng system.

Because Xlib is a C library, all symbols it defines live in the global namespace.  Fortunately in C++ you have the option of putting your Screen class in a namespace of your choosing.  As long as you then refer to it by its fully qualified name, you can avoid the name clash.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you are trying to compile on a linux system you should be using g++ to compile instead of gcc.